# Can't redirect to another page after form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a form and when the form is submitted it get the value of selected radio button and store in db, then I tried to redirect to another page but the result is that the current page is refreshed without update radio button value even if the value in the db is change, if I go to another page and return in the radio buttons page, the value are updates. How I can redirect to another page?

This is my code:

```
<?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $user["username"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user["role"]; ?></td>
                    <td class="right"><a href="delete_permission.php?idTratta=<?php echo $idTratta; ?>&user=<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>">Elimina permessi utente</a></td>
                    <td class="right"><form action="" method="post">  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"  value="1" <?php if ($user["role"] == 'configuratore') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" />C</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"  value="2"<?php if ($user["role"] == 'visualizzatore avanzato') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" />VA</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"   value="3"<?php if ($user["role"] == 'visualizzatore') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" />V </label><input type= "submit" name="sub_<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"value="Cambia"/></form></td>
                <?php
                   $sub='sub_';

                   if($_POST[$sub.''.$user["username"]]){
                   $permission=$_POST[$user["username"]];
                   $SimpleUsers->updateUserPermission($user["username"],$idTratta,$permission);
                   header('location: tratte.php' );
                   exit();
                  }
                 ?>

                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Add you full code here, i can't see the <form> tag in your code.

Comment: @KaushaMehta I can see it... on line 6...

Comment: @stwalkerster Omg sorry!

Comment: You didn't write the filename in form action that means on submit it redirects to current page. If you want to redirect it to another page then you have to write the name of file in action.

Comment: @KaushaMehta The asker is doing a header() call, so I suspect the intention is to use a Post-Redirect-Get pattern, which is nicer from a UX point of view anyway.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `header("Location:FILE_NAME.PHP")` won't work if there is any output written from the script, even a single space.

In your case, you are printing HTML (output), so, redirection is not working.

**Solutions:**

1) Add `ob_start()` at the very start of the page. This will store your output to buffer and redirection will occur.

2) Use Javascript redirection. Javascript redirection will occur irrespective of whether you are outputting something on browser or not.

Code:

```
$SimpleUsers->updateUserPermission($user["username"],$idTratta,$permission);
echo "<script>window.location.href='tratte.php';</script>";
//header('location: tratte.php' );
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In form you write like `<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"` and in PHP write like `if($_POST[$sub.''.$user["username"]]){` the both name are different.

Replace `<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"` with `<input type="radio" name="sub_<?php echo $user["username"]; ?>"`

Thanks!